# Strange repetitive ping pattern

Tags: lan, ping

A Hitron MoCA 2.5 device is locally (LAN 10.10.10.37/24) directly RJ-45 connected to a 1Gb switch. The cable is cat-6 and about 10 meters long. (the other Hitron is in another distant room, IP 10.10.10.36 - it doesn't really matter, Internet works fine).

A Linux server is RJ-45 connected to the same switch, and pinging other devices around (except the MoCA), the response is a constant ~0.2 ms.

But the MoCA gives interesting response times

```
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=8.56 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=7.25 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=6.25 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=5.79 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=4.27 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=3.22 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=2.24 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=1.24 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=0.248 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=8.28 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=26 ttl=64 time=7.23 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=6.24 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=28 ttl=64 time=5.20 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=29 ttl=64 time=4.23 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=30 ttl=64 time=3.22 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=31 ttl=64 time=2.22 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=1.22 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=0.225 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=8.06 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=7.22 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=6.23 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=5.20 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=4.21 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=3.20 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=2.21 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=41 ttl=64 time=1.22 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=42 ttl=64 time=0.223 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.37: icmp_seq=43 ttl=64 time=7.77 ms
```

Its response comes after 8 ms, then 7, then 6, 5, 4 ... then 8/7 again etc. indefinitely. The ping has 0% packet loss.

The switch has no special config (no VLAN, no priority, no QoS, all ports to defaults). The logs show no RX or TX failures anywhere.

I tried to change the cable, change the port connection to the switch but the ping response is always the same.

Does this recurrent pattern have any significance?

Comment: Apparently, that device processes ICMP echo requests only in some timeslots which is nothing irregular. However, host configurations/issues/implementations and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.